# What security issues should I be concerned with (Chromium - file-access-from-files)

Tags: c#, security, desktop-application, chromium

We have embedded Chromium into our C# desktop app.

The functionality we have created allows a user to write (and execute) visualization studies written in Processing.js, Raphael.js, Paper.js, D3.js and dygraph.js. We have built an IDE enabling users to write visualization studies and they can be run/executed on strategically placed HTML5 canvases within the software. Data specific to the work context is exposed to each visualization study.

This all works without the need for a web server. JSON and library files are accessed locally in Chromium using the file-access-from-files flag. The functionality works well however is there anything I need to take into consideration before releasing such functionality into the wild?

Security for example:

Is there a way to detect if a script sends data to an online address? Should I even be worrying about something like this?

What other things should I take into consideration given the functionality works locally on a users computer but can access data over a network or online? I am not a security expert and am looking for insight. Please note visualization studies are designed to be shared amongst users.

I look forward to some comments.